# Create a wordpress loop that only displays posts from the current day

Tags: wordpress, loops

I currently have a page that displays only 1 post because I wanted to have 1 post per day and that show up on the homage.

I have decided to have multiple posts in a day but I only want the homepage to display posts from the current day only.

What in my loop could I change to accomplish this?

My site is http://thatshitsawesome.com for reference.

Comment: could you post a sample of `your loop`?

Comment: Here is my loop currently:

`<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

 <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
     <div class="stumblr-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
   <div class="stumblr-content">
                 <?php the_content(''); ?>
             </div>
            
            <div class="stumblr-meta">
                <p><span class="stumblr-category"> THIS AWESOME SHIT IS CATEGORIZED AS <?php the_category(', ') ?> </span></p> 
            </div>
 <div class="clear"></div></div><!-- end post -->

<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: you need to change this line `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must increase the number of visible posts shown at most. I assume you know how to do this already as you've managed to limit it to one per query. For completion you can change it using the `posts_per_page` condition in the query arguments or in the *"Blog pages show at most"* value set under *settings* in the admin panel if you want to use the default value.

To limit posts to the current day use some specific *Time* parameters as defined in the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) reference. You need the conditions `year`, `monthnum` and `day`.

Example:

```
<?php 
// Limit query posts to the current day
$args = array(
    'year' => (int) date( 'Y' ),    
    'monthnum' => (int) date( 'n' ),    
    'day' => (int) date( 'j' ), 
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    $query->the_post();

    // ...
endwhile;
?>
```

If you're not using an explicit query but rely on the internal WP Query a common way to change the internal query is using the `pre_get_posts` action. Add the function below to your **functions.php** file to only show posts from the current day and only on the frontpage.

Example:

```
<?php
function limit_posts_to_current_day( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'year', (int) date( 'Y' ) );
        $query->set( 'monthnum', (int) date( 'n' ) );
        $query->set( 'day', (int) date( 'j' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_to_current_day' );
?>
```